# Porting a Python 2.X based project to Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, backport, python-2to3

I want to port a web application scanning framework from `Python 2.6.5-2.7.3` to `Python 3` without causing much harm to the compatibility with `Python 2.6+`.

I have read briefly about [six: Python 2 and 3 Compatibility Library](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) and `python-modernize`.

The framework I am intending to port uses libraries like `twisted` which are natively supported in Python 2. I have read http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Plan/Python3 which warns against usage of `2to3` at any stage during this process. 
The fact that `python-modernize` is a version of `2to3` has been another source of confusion. 

May I have some suggesions on the optimal approach to carry out such a porting and some common bugs that I might encounter ?

Comment: I found this very useful when I was porting: http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

Comment: `python-modernize` produces Python 2 code that should also work on Python 3. You could use it if you want to support both Python 2 and 3 from the same codebase (as twisted does). Presumably, you should call it manually unlike 2to3 that may be called automatically by `setup.py`.

Comment: The thing to be more concerned about is whether or not any of your dependencies (the greater the number, the more likely) are incompatible with Python 3. Many libraries will `pip install` successfully in Python 3, but have things like `except SomeError, exc:` (not compatible), etc. For instance, I just tried to use Python 3 in Heroku with Gunicorn and eventlet... no dice.

Comment: @Ffisegydd Thanks for pointing out. I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: This is a very broad question. "May I have some suggesions [sic] on the optimal approach to carry out such a porting and some common bugs that I might encounter ?"

Comment: I had this question and per today's research think that  the best forward and backward compatible solution, which is apparently so easy for new code is: 1.pip install future ; 2.Include: from __future__ import (absolute_import, division,    print_function, unicode_literals)  ; from builtins import * ; 3. Write standard Python 3 code. ;  4.Per the Quick-start guide — Python-Future documentation  ; http://python-future.org/quickstart.html